# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file Android

Tags: android, terminal

I'd like to use this command `./gradlew clean` in terminal in Android Stuido but I'm getting this message:

`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I'm trying to this in the project folder: `C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\Projectname>`

Have you any idea how can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`./gradlew` is used on Linux and Mac. On Windows you must use `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to navigate to android directly as you will find gradlew in that folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).